# apt-get throwing warning: "W: --force-yes is deprecated, use one of the options starting with --allow instead"

Tags: debian, apt, ubuntu-20.04

I'm running on Ubuntu 20.04 on Circle CI "machine" executor. Today I see that:

```
sudo apt-get install -y pkg1 pkg2
```

is throwing this warning:

```
W: --force-yes is deprecated, use one of the options starting with --allow instead
```

I'm not using "--force-yes". Where is this coming from? Even

```
sudo apt-get update
```

throws the same warning.

Comment: Did you have `APT::Get::force-yes "true"` set in your `/etc/apt/apt.conf` or in any files in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/`?

Comment: @mforsetti - that is it! Please add an answer saying that. Here is the relevant section from apt.conf:

// Auto "-y" for apt-get
APT {
  Get {
    Assume-Yes "true";
    force-yes "true";
  };
};

Comment: For any later wanderers in, the -y flag is short for --force-yes . Hence the deprecation warning there.

...Without the flag and the deprecation warning is new to me also. Defer to wiser greybeards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Today I see that:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install -y pkg1 pkg2
> ```
>
> is throwing this warning:
>
> ```
> W: --force-yes is deprecated, use one of the options starting with --allow instead
> ```

One can supply arguments to `apt-get` in at least three ways:

- using its specific CLI arguments, e.g. `apt-get --force-yes`;
- using `-o` CLI arguments with Configuration Item, e.g. `apt-get -o "APT::Get::force-yes=true"`; or
- using its configuration files, e.g.:

  ```
  APT {
      Get {
          force-yes "true";
      };
  };
  ```

  in `/etc/apt/apt.conf`.

If you don't see set arguments specified in your `apt-get` calls, you probably want to check `/etc/apt/apt.conf`, `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/*`, or [any other sources of `apt-get` configuration files](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/aptitude/ch02s05s05.en.html#idm6629).

Note that `--force-yes` is [dangerous](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/apt/apt-get.8.en.html) and you may want to remove this options from your `apt-get` configuration files.

Comment: Yes, I’m going to have to let Circle CI know about this problem with their images. In the mean time, I am just removing the force=yes part of the config file as a part of my job. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The first answer is right, but I could not understand from that what should be written instead of `--force-yes`. In my code, it was:

```
--allow-change-held-packages
```

This is taken from a comment below much of the same question at [Ubuntu 18 command apt-get dist-upgrade -qq --force-yes deprecated - Super User](https://superuser.com/a/1444431/1192848).

This is tested, the warning "W: --force-yes is deprecated, use one of the options starting with --allow instead" vanished. If this does not help, check the link for other `--allow-...` strings.

Comment: I don't believe you need to replace it, just remove it.

Comment: @KevinBuchs Good guess, strange wording then. I will not take the time to test it, anyone else who does so may comment.